# Нужно ли ставить запятую после слова "также"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить и в каких случаях?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **ТАКЖЕ ― это союз,** после союза запятая  не ставится, например: **Также** подписаны другие двусторонние документы.

2) **Запятая может ставиться или не ставиться после сочетания  ТАК ЖЕ** (наречие + частица) перед союзом КАК

А) Видишь, как всё здорово получилось, почти **так же, как** мечтали мы в детстве. Теневой кабинет составляется и функционирует точно **так же, как** и действующий.

Б) Режиссёры могут получаться из кого угодно, **так же как и** писатели.Многие, **так же как и** мы, бросив на блокпостах машины, брели сюда пешком.Он, **так же как и** я, был в Англии впервые.

Здесь составной союз ТАК ЖЕ КАК И.